# take string with multiple elements as an input and converting to vector c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to build a simple reference generator and am requiring the user to enter author names, which then become attributed to an object. However, I have tried dynamically allocating a string, and feeding to the function which sets the object's authors, but keep receiving these error messages:

```
no viable conversion from 'vector<std::__1::string>' (aka
      'vector<basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > >') to 'const
```

Main code:

```
int authors;
int aYear;
string aName = "?";
string aDate = "?";
string Org = "?";
string www = "?";
Harvard *refer;

refer = new Harvard();

cout << "Please enter as many details as you know. Type '0' if data is unknown." << endl;
cout << "Number of authors: " << endl;
cin >> authors;

if (authors != 0)
{
    string ss[authors];
    vector<char> writers = {};

    cout << "Enter the author names, pressing return when finished: " << endl;
    for(int a = 0; a < authors; a++)
    {
        getline(cin.ss[s]);
        writers.push_back(ss[a]);
    }
    refer->setAuthor(authors,&writers);
}
```

Function code:

```
// sets the authors of the source
void Harvard::setAuthor(int num, vector<char>* writers)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < writers->size(); i++)
    {
        authors.push_back(writers[i]);
    }
    return;
}
```

Is there any way I can take the authors first name and last name, and separate them inside the vector?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post your code [as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Thanks!

Comment: Strongly consider producing a [mre] and if making the MRE  doesn't expose the error and allow you to solve it, add the MRE to the question.

Comment: To separate them use `std:vector<std::pair<std::string,std::string>>` and then make the pair to insert using `std::make_pair(firstname,lastname)` That way each index of the vector has both pieces.

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not include the complete error message, it looks like it is cut off.  There is no `vector<string>` in the code you have shown (unless  `authors` inside of `Harvard::setAuthor()` is a `vector<string>`, but you don't show how it is used afterwards).

But, no matter, because the code you have shown is just all kinds of wrong anyway.  Typos, non-standard behaviors, etc.  For instance:

- `string ss[authors];` is a non-standard declaration of a variable-length array, which is supported only by a few compilers as a language extension.  Use `std::vector` for dynamic length arrays.
- `writers` is a dynamic array of single characters, that is hardly appropriate for names.  Use a vector of `std::string` instead.  In which case, you don't need the `ss` array anymore as it would be redundant (it is anyway, since you don't need a whole array of `string`s just to read individual `string`s one at a time.  You can reuse a single `string` variable for that purpose).
- `getline(cin.ss[s]);` is just wrong syntax.  You meant to use `,` instead of `.` and `a` instead of `s`.
- `writers.push_back(ss[a]);` is wrong, because you are trying to push a `string` into an array of `char`.

The code needs a good rewrite.  Try something more like this instead:

```
Harvard *refer = new Harvard;
// better:
// auto refer = make_unique<Harvard>();
// or
// unique_ptr<Harvard> refer(new Harvard);

cout << "Please enter as many details as you know. Type '0' if data is unknown." << endl;

cout << "Number of authors: " << endl;
int authors;
if ((cin >> authors) && (authors > 0))
{
    vector<string> writers(authors);

    cout << "Enter the author names, pressing ENTER after each one: " << endl;
    for(int a = 0; a < authors; a++)
    {
        getline(cin, writers[a]);
    }

    /* alternatively:

    vector<string> writers;
    writers.reserve(authors);

    for(int a = 0; a < authors; a++)
    {
        string name;
        getline(cin, name);
        writers.push_back(name);
    }
    */

    refer->setAuthor(writers);
}

// use refer as needed...

delete refer; // <-- only if not using unique_ptr!
```

```
// sets the authors of the source
void Harvard::setAuthor(const vector<string>& writers)
{
    // assuming authors is a vector<string> and not a vector<char> ...
    authors = writers;
}
```